# Simple java http client no server response

Tags: java, sockets

I'm attempting to write a simple Java http client that simply prints out one line of the server response. My problem is that I get no response from the server. Here is what I have, which is compiling and running with no explicit errors, it just hangs after I type a hostname, e.g. 'www.google.com':

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DNSTest {
    // Constructor
    public DNSTest() { }

    // Builds GET request, opens socket, waits for response, closes
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String line;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        //For each hostname
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){ 
            //Resolve the hostname to an IP address
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(line);

            //Open socket on ip address
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 80);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //Send request
            out.println("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n");

            //Read one line of input
            System.out.println("Response from "+line+": "+in.readLine());

        }
    }   
}
```

Any suggestions? Note that this assumes an 'index.html' exists - it still just hangs even if this is true.

Comment: Use a debugger to see where you code is hanging.

Comment: I know the out.println("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n"); goes out but System.out.println("Response from "+line+": "+in.readLine()); never gets called.

Comment: Works for me. I get: `Response from www.google.com: HTTP/1.0 302 Found`.

Comment: Really? Does it make a difference if I am doing this from the main method or not? I currently am...you're using the exact code above?

Comment: @gonzoc0ding I am using the code above from within a `main` method. I have just elided the `try`/`catch` block in favor of letting the method throw an exception. I also added the `line` declaration.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli I don't see how this is possible! I updated the code above with my full program. If you throw this in a file called DNSTest.java, and run it, it works? What could be the difference?

Comment: @gonzoc0ding yes it works. Alas, I don't have any suggestions ready as to understand why it hangs on your part. Except that the way you name your class or file is unlikely to play a role in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have been able to reproduce the problem by applying a small change to the code, so now it doesn't work on my machine and exhibits the same behavior as it does in your environment. I just changed the `out.println` call to a simpler `out.print`, and lo and behold, the program hangs *after* sending out the request but *before* the last `println` call.

As far as I can remember, HTTP requests need to supply an empty line after the headers, where the line separator must be the `\r\n` couple of characters. I suppose that your environment is such that `println` does not send the correct line separators (you can check the value of `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to verify which are the ones used on your system), so the request is interpreted by the server as incomplete and you get nothing on the input side. Some servers are quite forgiving and accept just `\n` as line separator, but if you happen to send `\n` explicitly and `\r\n` implicitly (by means of `println`) then your supposedly empty line contains the `\r` character and is no more seen as empty, possibly faulting the request to the effect of preventing the server to send back any response.

Therefore, my advice is to use `print` and send the correct line separators explicitly. Also, you very probably need to add a call to `flush`, maybe because there's an empty line in between the output - I don't really know, but without invoking `flush` my program still hangs. So, to sum up, the following should work:

```
// send request
out.print("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
out.flush();
// read one line of input
System.out.println("Response from " + line + ": " + in.readLine());
```

At least, I can confirm the program works on my machine with these changes, too.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to make

```
  out.flush();
```

after out.println(...);

This will send the data to the remote server. It looks like the data never leaves your local buffer.

I.e.

```
        Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 80);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        //Send request
        out.println("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n");
        out.flush();

        //Read one line of input
        System.out.println("Response from "+line+": "+in.readLine());
```

And if I type google.com it gives me:

```
 Response from google.com: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

---

If it doesn't work, try this:

```
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) 
            new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(false);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
        final InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        // construct BufferredStreamReader from the is
```

Note, the URL should be like "http://google.com" not just "google.com"

Comment: Still no go - just hangs after I type 'www.google.com' and hit enter. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Using your exact code above results in a hang still. What could be different between our environments? I have no firewall (that I'm aware of) and am just running OSX...

Comment: Are you sure it hangs? If you add any other System.out.println (e.g. right before out.pringln("GET... ) - do you see what it prints?

Comment: I see printlns all the way up until I try to read one line of server response: System.out.println("Response from "+line+": "+in.readLine()); E.g. If I print something right before this last line, I see it.

Comment: Further, if I remove the "+in.readLine()" from the last line of the program, it shows "Response from www.google.com: ".

Comment: Gotcha. Try the block of code I just added. Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: That worked. But I'm technically supposed to be using the manual method of opening a second and sending the request myself, as its for a project. I can't figure out why my code would work for you and not me other than environment.

Comment: Really hard to say as long as your method works for me. I would try to read the InputStream directly - i.e. read bytes from the response, and see where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same behavior when i tried the code of the 1st post (on Windows 8).
Same thing with all the others ways suggested in this topic.

Then I unninstalled my Antivirus (avast) and everything worked... :$