# Cant get the data sent by server to client in java

Tags: java, http, client, port

I wrote a program in java to check what a browser send to http sever.
The program noted the following texts( let name it `TEXT_BROWSER`)

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Now I made another program which send the `"TEXT_BROWSER"` to any website(google,my router(192.168.1.1))
but I got no response(no text from the server)
I want to know what is the error in my program.

My java program

```
//1streqbybrowser.txt contains TEXT_BROWSER<br/>
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
class TCPClient 
{
 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
 {
  String sentence;
  File f=new File("1streqbybrowser.txt");
  FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);  
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 80);
  DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  while((sentence = br.readLine())!=null)
   outToServer.writeBytes(sentence+"\n");
  System.out.println("Sending finished");
  while((sentence = inFromServer.readLine())!=null)
    System.out.println(sentence);
  clientSocket.close();
 }
}
```

**EDIT**

I changed 2nd line of TEXT_BROWSER from `Host: localhost` to`Host: 192.168.1.10` to send to my router(192.168.1.1), still not got any response from it

**EDIT AGAIN**
I did changes as mentioned by @andremoniy but only ast line of TEXT_BROWSER is sent to server and something received, 2nd loop does not end

```
>GET / HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: RomPager/4.07 UPnP/1.0
< EXT:
<
```

I noticed that inner loop never ends here.
Now what could be the reason?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959573/simple-java-http-client-no-server-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your program in part of `while` loop like that:

```
    while ((sentence = br.readLine()) != null) {
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + "\r\n\r\n");
        outToServer.flush();
        System.out.println(">" + sentence);
        while ((sentence = inFromServer.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println("< " + sentence);
    }
```

And you will see the result.

The main cause of your fail is 3 things:

1) you should use `\r\n` after each line

2) I you have to `flush` writer after each line

3) read server answer after each sent line

Comment: I edited the program as you mentioned but, the inner loop doesn't ends ever. Look above, I have mentioned the output.